# How to write loop statement in Stata?

Tags: loops, append, stata

I want to create a loop to append files that are similar but only differ on the date:

```
C:\AAA_201001.dta
C:\AAA_201002.dta
C:\AAA_201003.dta
...
C:\AAA_201501.dta
...
```

I want to create a loop to change the year (given by the first four numbers) and the month (last two numbers). How can I do this?

Comment: You should indicate some attempt to write code....

Comment: You mention a loop, so `help foreach` and `help forvalues`, should have been your first strategy. If not familiar, `search loop` would've gotten you there. Stata has excellent documentation; try taking advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't see what code you tried. This is mostly standard except for the small formatting trick to ensure that months cycle over 01 02 ... 11 12, not 1 2 ... 11 12.

```
forval y = 2010/2015 { 
    forval m = 1/12 { 
        local M : di %02.0f `m' 
        something referring to C:\AAA_`y'`M'.dta
    }
}
```

See here for [documentation of the formatting trick](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0051).

Use of `capture` may be useful for catching references to files that don't exist.

The example implies that you are storing data in the root of a PC under Windows, which I would advise against.